# What does 5以内 mean in 数学作业要在3分钟之内完成90道5以内的加减法题?

Tags: translation

> 数学作业要在3分钟之内完成90道5以内的加减法题

I can understand it as:

> The Math homework (you) must complete 90 questions of addition and subtraction within 3 minutes **under 5**. (what the heck?)

What does 5以内 mean in this sentence?

Comment: You understand It right, because *5以内* absolutely make no sense, and can't put anywhere to make It a **sense**.

Comment: @Tokenyet It does make sense indeed.

Comment: @dan, I don't want to argue, but I'm Chinese, If really spoke like that, no one know what's meaning... You might be a real Chinese than me :P At least, my area won't say like that.

Comment: @Tokenyet Interesting.  完成90道5以内的加减法 is a normal phrasing.  May I know what area you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5以内 is an arithmetic exercise for teaching kindergarten children.

https://wenku.baidu.com/view/4a6cb006ce2f0066f4332249.html

Answer (score 5):

It means questions that only involves positive numbers no larger than 5. For example, asking questions like "2+2=?" or "4-3=?".

Answer (score 0):

Read the phrase as this: 90道 [5以内的] [加减法] 题

5以内的 modifies 加减法. 5以内的加减法 as a whole modifies 题.

Answer (score 0):

The Math homework (you) must complete 90 questions of (addition and subtraction within 5) under 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To actually translate it, I went to the link provided by @Wayne Cheah. First of all, Although I never speak like that, the actual meaning is:

> The Math homework (you) must complete 90 questions within 3 minutes, and the math is about addition and subtraction in the range 0~5.

People come from different area would say different sentense, for example, in my area:

> 要在3分钟之内完成90道,加减和为0~5的加减法数学题

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't actually understand "加减和为0~5的加减法数学题".  It's not a standard/normal expression.

Comment: @dan, 和 means 总和, just like you told me,  It does make sense indeed. You just confused as me before. To prevent arguing about area-specified issue, I just stop here :P

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. but there is still a problem in your phrase 加减和为0~5的加减法数学题. 加减和 is illogical because 和 (as you explained as 总和) is only for addition, but not for subtraction. 减 is 差. 加减和 is wrong. That's why I couldn't understand it at my first read of it.

Comment: 总和 is total not for sum generally (area), but If you really focus on the narrow way, yes, that's confused If you think deeply. But in mathematical, 1 + (-1) is also making sense If you want to discuss in math, so I think don't be too serious on language :P

Comment: 五以内的加减法 does not mean 加减和为0~5的加减法. 4+2=? is a valid question for the former but not the latter. It is used to teach addition and subtraction for single-digit numbers as a foundation to teach the operations resulting in higher-magnitude numbers.

Comment: @zhantongz, you didn't see the document right? sigh...

Comment: @Tokenyet I do apologize that I was being too absolute. For me the natural progression was 五以内 then 二十以内 but now upon doing more research the most common meaning is the result has to be within 5 as well.

Comment: I regret to here for posting my view about this question, since area-specified, I'll response too many kind of your lang is wrong attack. I would not reply anymore, and just leave here...